# Why RouteDataRequestCultureProvider wasn't apply on Authorize process in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using a simple .Net Core Web Application and I redefine the route localization to use these rules in `Startup.cs`:

```
IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
{
    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
    new CultureInfo("fr-FR")
};

var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("fr-FR"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
};

var requestProvider = new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider();

localizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders =
    new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
    {
        requestProvider,
        new CookieRequestCultureProvider { CookieName = "app18n" }
    };

app.UseRouter(routes =>
{
    routes.MapMiddlewareRoute("{culture=fr-FR}/{*mvcRoute}", subApp =>
    {
        subApp.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

        subApp.UseMvc(mvcRoutes =>
        {
            mvcRoutes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{culture=fr-FR}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see, my default culture is `fr-FR`, but I accept two others: `en-US` and `en-GB`.

When I start my application, I have a redirection to the login page due to `AuthorizeAttribute` placed on `HomeController`.

When I decide to change the URL to `/en-US/Account/Login`, I get an `HTTP 404`  response.

**EDIT : Find A SOLUTION (suppose can be better)**

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.ReturnUrlParameter = "to";
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";

            var onRedirectToLoginBaseEvent = options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin;
            options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
            {
                var uri = new Uri(context.RedirectUri);
                context.RedirectUri = $"{uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)}/{context.HttpContext.GetRouteData().Values["culture"]}{uri.AbsolutePath}";
                return onRedirectToLoginBaseEvent(context);
            };

            var onRedirectToAccessDeniedBaseEvent = options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied;
            options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
            {
                var uri = new Uri(context.RedirectUri);
                context.RedirectUri = $"{uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)}/{context.HttpContext.GetRouteData().Values["culture"]}{uri.AbsolutePath}";
                return onRedirectToAccessDeniedBaseEvent(context);
            };

            var onRedirectToLogoutBaseEvent = options.Events.OnRedirectToLogout;
            options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
            {
                var uri = new Uri(context.RedirectUri);
                context.RedirectUri = $"{uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)}/{context.HttpContext.GetRouteData().Values["culture"]}{uri.AbsolutePath}";
                return onRedirectToLogoutBaseEvent(context);
            };

            var onRedirectToReturnUrl = options.Events.OnRedirectToReturnUrl;
            options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
            {
                var uri = new Uri(context.RedirectUri);
                context.RedirectUri = $"{uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)}/{context.HttpContext.GetRouteData().Values["culture"]}{uri.AbsolutePath}";
                return onRedirectToReturnUrl(context);
            };
        });
```

I think it is not the best solution but it works.

Comment: Have you added `{culture}` to your route in the `Account` controller?

Comment: No I haven't but why I have to do it ? The default route already have the {culture} tag

Comment: The default route is pointing to `/en-US/Account/Login`. You still need to have a controller that responds to that route/location. The default Account controller will have a route defined as something like `[Route("[controller]/[action]")]`. In order to respond to the correct culture, you need a route that responds to `[Route("{culture}/[controller]/[action]")]`. Otherwise it has no idea which controller to actually route you too.

Comment: You're right, there is a Route attribute in AccountController that I missed. I've changed route to `[Route("{culture=fr-FR}/[controller]/[action]")]` but now I have 404 on login page because application doesn't resolve culture